# How to get the response body text

Tags: java, android, retrofit, response

I'm creating a registration app, and there's almost all works, besides one problem.
Ok, now I will show you the code. That's a little long.

```
public interface SupportopApi {

@POST("/api/registration")
Call<ResponseBody> registration (@Body SupportopObj supportopObj);}
```

here's the interface.
Now i'll show you the model, that was parsed by JsonPoJo.

```
public class SupportopObj {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("firstName")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}}
```

Ok that was the model, i'm doing in fragments, so here's the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FrameLayout cont;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ApiClient.initializeInstance("https://supportop.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/");

    cont = findViewById(R.id.container);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new FragmentActivity()).commit();
}}
```

Here's the retrofit class, where i initialized the retrofit.

```
public class ApiClient {

private static ApiClient instance;

private SupportopApi supportopApi;


private ApiClient(String endpoint) {

    OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    clientBuilder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    supportopApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endpoint)
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(SupportopApi.class);
}


public static synchronized void initializeInstance(String endpoint) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ApiClient(endpoint);
    }
}


public static synchronized ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("PentairAPIClient has not been initialized.");
    }
    return instance;
}


public Call<ResponseBody> registration(SupportopObj supportopObj) {
    return supportopApi.registration(supportopObj);
}
}}
```

And here's the main fragment class.

```
public class FragmentRegistration extends Fragment {
View mainView;

EditText username, email, password, name;
Button button;

ApiClient pentairAPIClient = ApiClient.getInstance();

SupportopObj supportopObj = new SupportopObj();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.registration, container, false);

    username = mainView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    email = mainView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = mainView.findViewById(R.id.password);
    name = mainView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    button = mainView.findViewById(R.id.register);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            supportopObj.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
            supportopObj.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
            supportopObj.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

            updateApp();
        }
    });

    return mainView;
}

public void updateApp() {
    FragmentRegistration context = this;

    Call<ResponseBody> call = pentairAPIClient.registration(supportopObj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(response.body()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}}
```

Ok let me explain you what's my problem. When i click register, i have to get from `response.body` a message, where says registration completed successfully. First i try to give the Call registration Void, like this `Call<Void> registration`, but this gives back `response.body` null.

Now when i'm giving in call body `Call<ResponseBody> registration`, he gives back `OkHttp3:{ResponseBody$1@830038646440}`  something like this. 
When i'm doing debug in body there's a content, it seems like this

```
 content = {Buffer@830038501160} "[text="Registration Successfully completed"]"
```

[image]

Here's the image. How can I fix this, I want to get the text registration completed successfully.

Comment: I would read `ResponseBody` documentation and choose right method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

use body() method to get the response from your api and convert to string

> "body()" is the deserialized response body of a successful response and
>   string  is similar to "toString()"

```
public interface RetrofitService{
        @GET("/api/registration")
        Call<ResponseBody> registration(paramshere);//function to call api
    }

    RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> result = service.registration(params);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            System.out.println(response.body().string());//convert reponse to string
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make( cont , "Registered successfully",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);//pass your activity view as first param
            snackbar.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah that helped, but how can i do, that he printed "Registered successfully" without this "".

Comment: you can use snack bar to show the message, have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

convert response.body to jsonArray:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body());
String responseText = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("text");
```

you get "Registration Successfully completed" as responseText.